# Convergence with respect to the graph norm

Tags: convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, closed-graph

Let $T:A\subset E\to F$ be a linear closed operator with dense domain. (E,F are Banach spaces) and $x_n$ a sequence in A such that $||x_n-x||_E\to 0$. Let $||x||_1:=||x||_E+||T(x)||_F$ be the graph norm in A (A is a Banach space with this norm). I want to find out if we can deduce that even $||x_n-x||_1\to 0$ holds. I would appreciate any idea. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For example, on $\ell^1$ let $(T x)(n) = n x(n)$, with $A = \{x \in \ell^1 \mid \sum_n n |x(n)| < \infty\}$.  Take $x = 0$ and $x_n = e_n/n$, where $e_n$ is the sequence with $e_n(n) = 1$, $e_n(m) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: So we can even deduce that a dense subset for the norm $||\cdot||_E$ is not necessary dense with respect to the graph norm?

Comment: Suppose $T$ is unbounded, and $S$ is a set that is dense for the $\|\cdot\|_E$ norm.  For each $x \in S$, choose a sequence $y_n \in E$ such that $\|x - y_n\|_E < 1/n$ and $\|T y_n\|_F > 1$.  Let $Y$ be the union of these sequences for all $x \in S$.  Then the set $Y$ is again dense in $E$ for the norm $\|\cdot\|_E$, but it is not dense for the graph norm because $\|y\|_1 > 1$ for all $y \in Y$.